# Driving a LED with an open drain digital output

Tags: microcontroller, led, open-drain, stm32f2

I need to drive an LED from an [STM32F217ZG](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00263874.pdf).

So I was thinking about a classic circuit with a BJT. 
But then I saw that GPIO outputs of the microcontroller are configurable as open drain. 
Would this circuit work?

[image]

The LED has a 20mA forward current and a 2V forward voltage. Considering \$R=(3.3-2)/0.02\$ it should be on, if GPIO is Hi-Z and off, if it is GND, right?

I don't see why this circuit would not work but I've never seen it before, so I just want to be sure before designing it.

**Edit:**
Then you mean it is better to do this:

[image]

**Edit 2:**
Finally here is the schematic I'll be using (the output GPIO LED6FAIL is 3.3V and it's a push-pull):

[image]

Comment: Regarding your 2nd edit, if the `LED6_FAIL` pin is open-drain, that circuit won't work. You should use steven's circuit.

Comment: @m.Alin - damien said in a comment to my answer that he would use a "regular" push-pull configuration instead of the open-drain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This circuit will work, but not be efficient, power-wise. If the output is high the LED is on and you'll have 20 mA current through LED and resistor.

But with the output low, the LED is short-circuited and therefore off, but the resistor current will be even higher: 50 mA!, which is not only bad for your wallet and the environment, but also for the output pin; most I/Os will only allow 25 mA.

Place the LED in series with the resistor. Then a high output won't light the LED because the output FET is switched off. A low output will draw the 20 mA through LED, resistor and open-drain output.

Note that this will invert the logic: in your first schematic the LED will be off when the output is active, in the second circuit it will be on with active output.

**edit**
If the output can't sink enough current you'll need an external transistor to increase that.

[image]

If the output is active (low) there will flow a 1.5 mA from +3.3 V through Q2's emitter-base junction, R2 and Q1. That 1.5 mA will allow Q2 to source more than 100 mA for a typical general-purpose transistor. You will only get about 22 mA, though, because R1 won't allow more.

If Q1 is off there won't be any base current through Q1, so the LED will remain off. Q1 will have a small leakage current, and to avoid that this would get amplified by Q2 I added R3. As long as the leakage current is less than 0.7 V / 15 kΩ = 50 µA all the leakage current will flow through R3, so that will ensure Q2 will be completely off.

Comment: Thank you I edited my answer is it what you meant?

Comment: @damien - Yep, that's it. (Always check if the output can sink the required current!) I also added a not to my answer that the alternative circuit inverts the logic.

Comment: About the sink current, if the absolute maximum rating is 20mA and the LED has 20mA forward current I guess it is not okay to use it this way right? The I/O could damaged?

Comment: @damien - Not OK indeed: you should not operate the device at Absolute Maximum Ratings (AMR) for a longer time. That's a standard phrase in the AMR section of all datasheets. In that case you have to use the open-drain output to drive an external transistor. I added a schematic to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in this case i don't see the purpose of using the OUTPUT as an open drain. I think it is easier to use it in push-pull configuration and just put a base resistance on the BJT. It seems to be the same isn't it?

Comment: In the circuit that Stevenvh added the drive from the source into the R2 1.5K ohm resistor can be open-drain or push-pull. Both will work just fine.

Comment: @damien - As Michael says. But it was *you* who started about the open-drain, not me! :-) If you're driving from a push-pull output you don't need R3, and then the circuit is the mirror image of the third schematic in the question, with a PNP instead of an NPN.